# Is it possible to use mvp4g to create a library?

Tags: gwt, mvp4g

I'm creating a GWT application using mvp4g. As part of the application, I'm also creating a library in another gwt module; this library follows the mvp4g pattern, but here I'm creating everything by myself, Views, Presenters, Events, Handlers.

The library is used in different parts of the main application. Basically, the library gives a main widget which is configured depending on the section of the application, that's enabling features by adding other widgets (from the same library) to the main widget.

Also, the library is suposed to be used in other projects, therefore other widgets can be created and added to the main widget.

So, I'd like to know if there's a way to use mvp4g to create this library, or if mvp4g is only used for applications. Is there any other mvp library that allow to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you find an answer useful close the question or post an update to the question. To know why this is important Read -  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

mvp4g allows you to follow a structured approach to developing with gwt code. It should be usable in a library project without entry point as easily as in project with entrypoint.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create one or more client libraries and add them as dependencies to a webapp you are compiling using the GWT compiler.

See `Dividing code into multiple modules`, here: 
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.

Maven or Gradle are good options for collecting, building and packaging your code into functional units.